# Sorting a list of not previously known elements (List<?>)

Tags: java, sorting, generics, quicksort

I am implementing a generic class for be the base class for my service classes, where I should have one for each entity class in my application. Besides methods for Insert, Update or Delete items (all already done), I have a method to return a list of items, where I need sort this list, and return a sub-set corresponding to one page of a variable size of elements.

My question is related to the sorting process, where I have this implementation right now:

```
protected List<E> ordenaLista(List<E> lista, int ordem) {
    return this.quick_sort(lista, 0, lista.size());
}

protected List<E> quick_sort(List<E> v,int ini, int fim) {
    int meio;

    if (ini < fim) {
        meio = partition(v, ini, fim);
        quick_sort(v, ini, meio);
        quick_sort(v, meio + 1, fim);
    }

    return v;
}

protected int partition(List<E> v , int ini, int fim) {
    E pivo;
    pivo = v.get(ini);
    int topo = ini;

    for (int i = ini + 1; i <= fim; i++) {
        int result = v.get(i).toString().compareTo(pivo.toString());
        if (result > 0) {
            v.set(topo, v.get(i));
            v.set(i, v.get(topo+1));
            topo++;
        }
    }
```

this code should work only if the List had only primitive elements (Integer or Float), but what I will have instead of E is one of the entity classes from my project. In this case, I should make the comparation (`v.get(i).toString().compareTo(pivo.toString())`) with the atributes from each class. And more, with the atribute indicated by ordem, which represent a "position" for the atribute, like this:

Entity: Usuario
Atributes: login, senha, pnome, unome, email
Ordem: 1=login, 2=senha, 3=pnome, 4=unome, 5=email

Anyone can point me a direction to accomplish that?

Comment: Rather than comparing toString() you can implement comparable in your entity class.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use [`Compararator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your entity classes implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).
Thus you'll have

```
v.get(i).compareTo(pivo)
```

instead of

```
v.get(i).toString().compareTo(pivo.toString());
```

Comment: Fair point, by `Comparator` would provide a more flexible solution and wouldn't require every entity to implement the `Comparable` interface - just saying ;)

Comment: Right, but with flexibility comes complexity - you need a way of getting the right comparator, and the comparator depends on the class of the element being compared. So you'd end up with a factory method (in a separate class) which means additional maintenance cost.

Comment: By with `Comparable`, you get a one "shoe fits all" approach, there's no way to take two lists of the same object and get two different results (one ascending, one descending, for example)

Answer (score 1):

Make a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for each entity class and use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort the lists.

Your generic base class could define an abstract getComparator() method.

Answer (score 1):

### You Could...

Require the entities to implement the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, this means you'd need to change your classes generics to handle the entities implementation requirements...

```
public class SomeClass<E extends Comparable> ... {
```

This will also require that all your class must implement the `Comparable` interface, which might not always be practical (as you might not always control the entities)

### You Could

Provide the means to pass a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to your sort methods instead (or any of the methods that might need to compare the elements)

```
protected List<E> quick_sort(List<E> v,int ini, int fim, Comparator<E> comparator) {
```

Then instead of...

```
int result = v.get(i).toString().compareTo(pivo.toString());
```

You would be able to use...

```
int result = comparator.compareTo(v.get(i), pivo);
```

This provides you with some more flexibility in providing a variable comparator, which could be used to change the way that a single object can be compared based on your needs (sorting on the last name instead of the first name for example)